# Hadoop mapreduce error : PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1

Tags: python, xml, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to convert xml files through a mapreduce job and receive the error :

```
2023-04-04 09:41:52,515 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2023-04-04 09:42:12,676 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1680592009322_0021_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED 
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
```

I'm lauching it with the command :

```
yarn jar /opt/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.2.1.jar \
        -file "script/mapper_convert_xml.py" -mapper "python3 mapper_convert_xml.py" \
        -file "script/reducer_convert_xml.py" -reducer "python3 reducer_convert_xml.py" \
        -input /input/philharmonie_data/AIC94.xml -output /output/philharmonie_data
```

My script have the header `#!/usr/bin/env python` and I give `chmod 744` to mapper, the reducer and ElementTree.py scripts.

The script run fine in local mode with the command line

```
cat /home/philharmonie_data/AIC94.xml | python3 /script/mapper_convert_xml.py | python3 /script/reducer_convert_xml.py
```

Here is my mapper script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from operator import itemgetter
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys
import json

parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
tree = ET.fromstring(sys.stdin.read().encode("utf-8", "replace"))

for element in tree:
    child_values = ""
    for child in element:
        if child.tag == "{http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim}controlfield":
            child_values = child_values + child.attrib["tag"] + "\t" + child.text + "_|_"
            
        if child.tag == "{http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim}datafield":
            for field in child:
                code_uni = child.attrib["tag"] + "$" + field.attrib["code"]
                value = field.text
                if code_uni is not None:
                    child_values = child_values + code_uni + "\t" + value + "_|_"
            
    print(child_values)
```

I've try to `chmod -x` the scripts, add the `#!/usr/bin/env python3` headers on scripts.

The use of `-files` instead of `-file` in the command line don't change the error.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44352818/error-python3-4-java-lang-runtimeexception-pipemapred-waitoutputthreads) I try to execute this command with no change in the error :

```
yarn jar /opt/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.2.1.jar \
        -file "script/mapper_convert_xml.py" -mapper "python3 mapper_convert_xml.py --python-bin /usr/bin/python3" \
        -file "script/reducer_convert_xml.py" -reducer "python3 reducer_convert_xml.py --python-bin /usr/bin/python3" \
        -input /input/philharmonie_data/AIC94.xml -output /output/philharmonie_data
```

Edit : I also tryed to change the sys.stdin with no change

```
import io

# Set encoding explicitly
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer, encoding='utf-8')
```

As the wordcount example run, I suspect the `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`  line to break the code in HDFS.  Any Idea on how to make the job work ? Thanks

Comment: What's the actual error? You should be given a link to the task logs somewhere near the log that you pasted.

Comment: When you use `sys.stdin.read()`, that's only reading one line from your file. Xml files typically are indented tags over multiple lines. Are we to assume that you've correctly ran `hdfs put /home/philharmonie_data/AIC94.xml` command already for your files? (maybe your input path is empty?)

Comment: That being said, are you required to use Hadoop streaming over alternative tools like `spark-xml` library and use `pyspark` instead?

Comment: Thanks, I've no necessity to use hadoop stream and I will use pyspark